# Derivation of an over-parametrized Fisher information for categorical distribution, with $n\ge3$

Tags: categorical-data, fisher-information

Having found interesting this [earlier discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130861/fisher-information-matrix-determinant-for-an-overparameterized-model) I wonder if there is any specific example of building a Fisher information matrix (FIM) in case $n\ge3$. I tried myself, but every time, I am getting stuck somewhere and I am unable to make a matrix that has vector of ones as one of its eigenvectors.

**UPDATE**

After reviewing my post with fresh eyes, I would like to clarify better my request.

Since with $n=2$, we have $\ell_n(p,1-p)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\ln(p)+(n-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)\ln(1-p)$, I can see how the **proper** Fisher information takes the form $I(p,1-p)=\frac1{p(1-p)}\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}$.

However, I am unable to develop it for a general case with $n\ge3$, thanks!

**UPDATE 2**

After tinkering a bit, I guess that if we do not re-parametrize to dimension $d-1$, then the score function and Fisher information become as follows.

$s(\mathbf p)=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{X_1}{p_1}-\color{red}{\frac{X_d}{p_d}}\\\color{red}{\vdots}\\\frac{X_{d-1}}{p_{d-1}}-\color{red}{\frac{X_d}{p_d}}\\\frac{X_d}{p_d}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{X_1}{p_1}\\\vdots\\\frac{X_{d-1}}{p_{d-1}}\\\frac{X_d}{p_d}\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}\color{red}{\frac{X_d}{p_d}\\\vdots\\\frac{X_d}{p_d}}\\0\end{bmatrix}=\text{diag}^{-1}(\mathbf p)\mathbf X-\color{red}{\mathbf e_d^T\text{diag}^{-1}(\mathbf p)\mathbf X}(\mathbf 1_d-\mathbf e_d)$

$I(\mathbf p)=\begin{bmatrix}\frac1{p_1}+\color{blue}{\frac1{p_d}}&\color{blue}{\dots}&&\color{blue}{\frac1{p_d}}\\\color{blue}{\vdots}&\color{blue}{\ddots}&&\\&&\frac1{p_{d-1}}+\color{blue}{\frac1{p_d}}&\\\color{blue}{\frac1{p_d}}&&&\color{blue}{\frac1{p_d}}\end{bmatrix}=\text{diag}^{-1}(\mathbf p)(\mathbf I_d-\mathbf e_d\mathbf e_d^T)+\color{blue}{\mathbf e_d^T\text{diag}^{-1}(\mathbf p)\mathbf e_d^T}\mathbf 1_d\mathbf 1_d^T$

Note that $\color{red}{\mathbf e_d^T\text{diag}^{-1}(\mathbf p)\mathbf X=\frac{X_d}{p_d}}$ and $\color{blue}{\mathbf e_d^T\text{diag}^{-1}(\mathbf p)\mathbf e_d^T=\frac1{p_d}}$ are both scalars.

At this point, my questions are: (1) did I make any mistakes? and (2) do Pearsons's theorem and Wilk's test have something in common?

$\begin{align}
n(\hat{\mathbf p}-\mathbf p)^T I(\mathbf p)(\hat{\mathbf p}-\mathbf p)
&=n(\hat{\mathbf p}-\mathbf p)^T(\text{diag}^{-1}(\mathbf p)(\mathbf I_d-\mathbf e_d\mathbf e_d^T))(\hat{\mathbf p}-\mathbf p)\\
&+\color{blue}{\frac1{p_d}}(\hat{\mathbf p}-\mathbf p)^T\mathbf 1_d\mathbf 1_d(\hat{\mathbf p}-\mathbf p)\\
&=\underbrace{\lVert\sqrt n\text{diag}^{-\frac12}(\mathbf p)(\mathbf I_d-\mathbf e_d\mathbf e_d^T)(\hat{\mathbf p}-\mathbf p)\rVert_2^2}_{\xrightarrow{(d)}\chi_{d-1}^2}+\underbrace{\lVert p_d^{-\frac12}\mathbf 1_d^T(\hat{\mathbf p}-\mathbf p)\rVert_2^2}_{=0}
\end{align}$

**UPDATE 3**

OK, I definitely made some mistakes above, first and foremost because $n\frac{\hat p_j-p_j}{p_j}$ does not converge to $\chi_1^2$ alone.

Also, I should said Wald's test, instead of Wilk's test. In any case, I realised that once you re-parametrize the problem and consider only $d-1$ parameters, then you can figure out Fisher information, and use Wald's test to explain Pearson's theorem.

So the main question remains unanswered. **What is the over-parametrised FIM for** $\mathbf{n\ge3}$?